# error with Installation of rpy2 on mac

Tags: python, macos, docker, jupyter, rpy2

I am trying to install rpy2 on my mac machine so I can run python and R both on a Jupyter notebook. I tried to use pip and docker image and both methods did not work. Below are errors I received. Would you please advise how to get rid of these errors?

```
pip install rpy2
Downloading/unpacking rpy2
  Downloading rpy2-2.8.5.tar.gz (184kB): 184kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/k7/d_26z86n1hlcd8ffkr1_htgh0000gn/T/pip_build_rhadadi/rpy2/setup.py) egg_info for package rpy2
    Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no command 'R' in the PATH.
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no command 'R' in the PATH.

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/k7/d_26z86n1hlcd8ffkr1_htgh0000gn/T/pip_build_rhadadi/rpy2
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/rhadadi/.pip/pip.log

$ docker run --rm -p 8888:8888 rpy2/rpy2:2.8.x

docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint romantic_mirzakhani (0ae580822b3be34f3a12c8b402f626fa1c57b75b2fd229fa2e571bcf6ad19e75): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:8888 failed: port is already allocated.
ERRO[0000] error getting events from daemon: context canceled
```

Comment: `Bind for 0.0.0.0:8888 failed: port is already allocated.` Did you try running it on a different port? You can run `ps -A` to see if there is a copy of the process already running.

Comment: "Tried to guess R's HOME but no command 'R' in the PATH" => Change your PATH setting.

Comment: Thank you user2896976 and Jeroen Heier. It was running on a different port.